# expression list treated as compound expression in initializer in creating a Pointer to a vector of Mat's

Tags: c++, c, opencv, vector, mat

I'm getting the below error messages on this line `vector<Mat> *std_carrayTovectorm(m, 2);` when trying to make a c array to feed to my function that converts a C array of Mat's into a C++ vector. I think my code is right but not sure if it is my `std_carrayTovectorm` function that is the issue. How can I edit my creation of the C array or the `std_carrayTovectorm` function to create a vector of Mat's from a C array.

Thank you

//expression list treated as compound expression in initializer
        //invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘std::vector*’

```
typedef vector<Mat> vector_Mat;

    vector_Mat* std_carrayTovectorm(Mat* a, size_t len) {
        vector<Mat>* v = new vector<Mat>;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) 
            v->push_back(a[i]);
        return v;
    }


    int main( int argc, char** argv )
    {

        Mat img1 = imread( "/home/w/d1");
        Mat img2 = imread( "/home/w/d1");

        Mat* m[2] = { new Mat (img1), new Mat (img2) };
        vector<Mat> *std_carrayTovectorm(m, 2);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `m` is an array of pointers to `Mat` and `std_carrayTovectorm` expects an array of `Mat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems regarding pointers...and you pasted the prototype of a function in the main and forgot to remove the return type !

Here is a modified program to put you back on the right track. Notice that i modified `vector_Mat` to a vector of pointers to `Mat`...

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

#include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

typedef vector<Mat*> vector_Mat;

vector_Mat* std_carrayTovectorm(Mat** a, size_t len) {
    vector_Mat* v = new vector_Mat();
    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) 
        v->push_back(a[i]);
    return v;
}


int main( int argc, char** argv )
{

    Mat img1 = imread( "one.jpg");
    Mat img2 = imread( "two.jpg");

    Mat* m[2] = { &img1, &img2 };
    vector_Mat* v=std_carrayTovectorm(m, 2);

    imwrite("three.jpg",*((*v)[0]));
    imwrite("four.jpg",*((*v)[1]));
            delete v;
    return 0;
}
```

Bye,

EDIT : without modifying `vector_Mat` :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

#include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

typedef vector<Mat> vector_Mat;

vector_Mat* std_carrayTovectorm(Mat** a, size_t len) {
    vector_Mat* v = new vector_Mat();
    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) 
        v->push_back(*a[i]);
    return v;
}


int main( int argc, char** argv )
{

    Mat img1 = imread( "one.jpg");
    Mat img2 = imread( "two.jpg");

    Mat* m[2] = { &img1, &img2 };
    vector_Mat* v=std_carrayTovectorm(m, 2);

    imwrite("three.jpg",((*v)[0]));
    imwrite("four.jpg",((*v)[1]));

    delete v;
    return 0;
}
```

Bye,

Comment: ....Thank you for your help on this...it worked perfectly...but my associate doesn't want me to change vector_Mat*...do you have other advice?

Comment: @user3517736 : your associate is right, it's easy to do it without modifying `vector_Mat`. I edited my answer accordingly.